# Login Flows (Salesforce) with IE11

Tags: visual-workflow, internet-explorer, loginflow

I have one simple login flow which is having one flow(simple flow like one screen) and  which is applies to community user.When I logging into portal in  IE which is not working but except all browsers are working perfect,if anybody have suggestion please let me know

Comment: What problem or error is occurring?

Comment: The Problem is when we click on the login button which is loading ,but not logging in to community portal

Answer (score 1):

This could be a known issue check this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Z5NAAU).

At present the only workaround is to use chrome and firefox.

You can build something custom to overcome this instead of using login flow